# Embeding all variables in an imputation function in R

Tags: r

Finding mean without outliers and then imputing that mean for NA values

```
{
lq<-quantile(churn.data.frame.2$avg6mou,probs = 0.25, na.rm = TRUE)
uq<-quantile(churn.data.frame.2$avg6mou,probs = 0.75, na.rm = TRUE)
step<-1.5*(uq-lq)
xyz<- churn.data.frame.2$avg6mou[!is.na(churn.data.frame.2$avg6mou)]
imputation.mean<-mean(xyz[(xyz>lq-step)&(xyz<step+uq)])

churn.data.frame.2$avg6mou[which(is.na(churn.data.frame.2$avg6mou))]<- imputation.mean
 }
```

Hey guys I am a newbie at R and am kind of stuck in embedding the data.frame in a function. The above code I have written finds the mean of a certain variable(column) without the outliers and imputes this mean for the missing values.

Since I have 157 variables to deal with I want to embed this in a user-defined function and later use it in a for-loop. 
I am having trouble in writing a function which accesses each column of the data.frame and implements the above behavior.

would appreciate any help/suggestions for an effective solution

Answer (score 2):

You are referring to column `churn.data.frame.2$avg6mou`. You can also access it using `churn.data.frame.2[, "avg6mou"]`. You can also change `churn.data.frame.2$avg6mou[!is.na(churn.data.frame.2$avg6mou)]` to `churn.data.frame.2[!is.na(churn.data.frame.2$avg6mou), "avg6mou"]`, etc.

Answer (score 1):

You want to apply the same function to all 157 columns of your dataframe and return a vector with the means for each column? The apply family of functions should help you do this while avoiding the for loop.

You can simply replace the specific columns (`churn.data.frame.2$avg6mou`) with a general a general vector reference. Then use a function wrapper.

Something like this should work:

```
your_function <- function(a_vector){
  lq<-quantile(a_vector,probs = 0.25, na.rm = TRUE)
  uq<-quantile(a_vector,probs = 0.75, na.rm = TRUE)
  step<-1.5*(uq-lq)
  xyz<- a_vector[!is.na(a_vector)]
  return(mean(xyz[(xyz>lq-step)&(xyz<step+uq)]))
 }
```

You can then use an apply function to apply this to your data frame:

```
your_col_means <- sapply(df,your_function)
```

If you'd prefer a list for your result then you should use lapply instead of sapply.